# how to access fields in belongs_to association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i am working on a rails application which has a User and Authorization models. Eacch User can have many Authorizations and every Authorization belongs to a particular user. i used belongs_to association for this. now when i am trying to access authorizations of a particular user using

```
user = User.find(params(:id))
auth = user.authorizations
```

now the problem is when i try to access the fields of Authorization using

```
auth.id
```

i get no method found error but the following

```
Authorization.first.id
```

works fine. what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

If user `has_many :authorizations` then `user.authorizations` returns array of the user's authorizations (actually it returns `AR:Relation` but it doesn't matter now). So if you want to get `id` of the first authorization you can use `user.authorizations.first` and if you want to get all the ids of the authorization for this user you can use `user.authorizations.map(&:id)`

Comment: Thanks i missed some basics over here

Answer (score 1):

```
 auth = user.authorizations
```

Now auth will be an array of Authorization objects

```
 auth.first.id
```

will work unless the array is not empty

Comment: @sounder Thanks i missed some basics over here

Answer (score 1):

```
@authorizations = user.authorizations
```

will return an list of authorizations. So you just form a loop then get field values. Example

```
@authorizations.each do |auth|
  auth.id
end
```

Comment: Thanks i missed some basics over here